# android permission READ_SMS granted but not working (even using REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS)

Tags: android

I want to create an app that reads all inbox sms and when i tap on a message from the list it sends the data to another activity which contains another list to forward the message to.
the reading SMS worked perfectly before i started working on the other activity.
once i finished the whole app , i ran the application on phone but when there are messages it gives me that android app unfortunately stopped but when i delete all threads it start the app normally with no messages in it. what might be the error ??

here is my main activity and i added the read sms permission in Manifest

```
public class main extends ListActivity {
    final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(), "android.permission.READ_SMS") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(main.this, new String[]{"android.permission.READ_SMS"}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
                return;
            }
            readAllSMS();
        } else {
            readAllSMS();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    readAllSMS();
                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(main.this, "READING SMS Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    protected void readAllSMS() {
        Toast.makeText(main.this, "READING SMS Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        List<SMSData> smsList = new ArrayList<>();

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(c);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
                SMSData sms = new SMSData();
                sms.setBody(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString());
                sms.setNumber(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString());
                smsList.add(sms);
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        c.close();

        setListAdapter(new ListAdapter(this, smsList));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        SMSData sms = (SMSData) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        String msg = "number : " + sms.getNumber() + "\nsent : " + sms.getBody();
        sendSMS(msg);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sms.getBody(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void sendSMS(String message) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("SMS_Message",message);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the crash is caused by the lack of a permission? What do you have in your logs? Can you paste the relevant parts of the call stack?

Comment: you are right the error i got is not from the permissions it is from android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout